# How to boot a .efi file using QEMU?

Tags: uefi, qemu, iso

Well, thats all, how can I boot a .efi file in QEMU? I'm almost new to this EFI world and I dont know how to start, should I make an iso, what would be the internal structure of that iso? Thanks in advance!